# What is the relation and/or difference between Game Theory and Markov Chain Model?

Tags: markov-process, game-theory

I am doing some work regarding my master's thesis in networks security.

I have decided to work with Game Theory, calculating the Nash Equilibrium for a two player zero sum game.

However, I have also read that Markov Chain Model can be used to calculate Nash Equilibrium and this is confusing me.

What is the relation between both Markov Chain and Game Theory?

Comment: I'm only _guessing_ that it refers to an alternative MC-type of algorithm that calculates Nash Equilibrium...

Comment: This would need a reference & more details about what the source document exactly said about using Markov chains.  In general asking for connections between Markov chains and game theory is too broad

Answer (score 0):

You mean the relation between Game Theory and Markov Decision Process.
If you want a common keyword search for the Backward Induction (backward induction solutions are Nash equilibria but the inverse is not necessarily true). The backward induction can be used to solve the MDP by finding out what we call Rewards in MDP. You are right there is a common background but Game Theory is much used in economy and management decisions and MDP in IA decisions, robotics, maintenance decisions, ... But both can solve in many contexts the same problems.